# Two people are looking for each other. Is it faster for both to actively search, or for one to search while the other stays still?

Tags: game-theory, brownian-motion, random-walk

Choose among two actors randomly and place the chosen actor at the origin. Place the other actor in the unit circle uniformly at random. Both actors move at the same speed. Both actors are said to have "found" the other actor if they are at or within a distance $\delta$ of one another. Both actors know only their position relative to where they were initially placed. Both actors also know that the other actor must be within a distance $1$ of them. That is all either actor knows. Consider two scenarios: one, the actor placed uniformly at random in the unit circle is "searching" (adopting a strategy profile to minimize time spent before finding the other actor) for the other actor while the other stays still; two, both actors are searching for one another.

Neither actor in either scenario knows whether or not they were placed at the origin. A searching actor does not know whether the other actor is searching as well (that is, a searching actor does not know which scenario it is).

1. What is the best response strategy profile for the searching actor(s)?
2. Is the first or second scenario faster (on average), or are they both equal in terms of time spent searching?

Comment: A pretty good strategy is for both actors to go toward the center of the circle as fast as possible.  The same works for Grand Central station.

Comment: To make the question non-trivial it seems like you either need (1) at least one of the actors is disoriented, or (2) at least one of the actors does not want to meet.  Probably (1) is more in keeping with the spirit of your question.

Comment: If neither actor is aware of the other's strategy, standing still is definitely not going to work. They can only assume that the other one will be standing still, to prevent the situation where both are waiting indefinitely.

Comment: I'm considering two scenarios: one where both actors search, and one where only one actor searches. The catch is that the searching actor doesn't know which scenario it is. Surely then the best response is not only moving towards the center as fast as possible? (But that does suggest both actors searching is faster than only one actor searching.)

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how I'm to describe having a disoriented actor, or what that would really mean for its behavior.

Comment: Here is a better setup for your problem: Choose one of A,B at random, and place at the origin.  Place the other uniformly at random in the unit circle.  Each player henceforth knows their position relative to their own starting point, but not their absolute position.  The problem is therefore symmetric, and the initial information is that the other person's starting point is within 1 of my starting point.

Comment: @vadim123 OK, I think I've adopted your formulation correctly. Please point out mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that they don't know where the origin is otherwise it would be a simple strategy for both to move there. The origin is just convenient coordinates for us to track the problem and is the initial location of the first player.

If you move to new coordinates by subtracting the movements of the first player from both them and the second player you get back to one player stands still and the other moves, but now the second play moves between zero and twice the speed available. Therefore what ever strategy they are using it would work twice as fast. Therefore the answer is both should move.